# SSL issue with oauth ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, oauth, stripe-connect

I'm attempting to use an oauth library so I can work with stripe connect.

https://github.com/intridea/oauth2 is the gem I am using. However whenever I actually attempt to use it like so:

```
 @resp = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :params => {:scope => 'read_write'})
```

every time I get just this error.

```
Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
```

I've tried so many different solutions but I can't get anything to work. Everything online so far has said I should update a certificate, which I did using 4 different ways I found here.

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found a work around by adding

config.force_ssl = false

to config/application.rb